# How see a 3D picture from all angles hosted on a link on my phone by moving my phone?

Tags: javascript, android, 3d, x3d

So, I am working on a project where a 3D picture is hosted on a link and if I open the link on my phone I will see a 3D picture and when I move my phone around I can see different viewpoints of the picture. For example, if I move my phone to right I can see the right view of the 3D image inside my phone if I move my phone up I can see the upper view of the image so on and so forth.

Can someone guide me how I can solve this problem?

What I did until now?

I wrote code to get access of the sensors of the mobile phone when you click the link it asks for permission and when you move your phone it shows Alpha, Beta and Gamma (Euler Angles) on the screen.

Comment: Look here: https://immersive-web.github.io/webxr-samples/ (also, this is OT for here unless you have code to show and a specific problem to solve)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link sure, I will show the code. @ChrisG

Comment: @ChrisG the code is pretty big! Should I share the link can you see inside the browser? One more thing to add I want to create something that if my phone goes inside a google cardboard I can see the 3D picture by moving my head around or phone around hope it makes sense.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense; did you look at the [Cardboard app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.samples.apps.cardboarddemo) yet? Are we talking about VR here? Like the StreetView demo in the cardboard app? Or do you want to create your own 3D environment? In that case you should go to here: https://developers.google.com/cardboard/develop

Comment: When you will click on this link you will see a 3D picture which you can see around by swiping you fingers on the screen. But my task is to move my phone around and see the picture from all views and angles. (http://metagrid1.sv.vt.edu/~polys/Forestry2020/FishburnFinal/Plot1_Mobile.html)

Comment: I get it. The easiest way to create this is the Google Streetview app; tap "Create" then "Photo Sphere"; this will generate a 360° photograph which you can then view in full VR 3d in the Cardboard app.

Comment: Thanks for the information. But if without using any app or leaving google cardboard aside can I only use my phone and move around and see all around because the picture is already 3D. Because in the future user will scan a QR code then a they will be directed to this link and they will simple move their phone around and can see the 3D image by device rotation. I am sorry to bother you so much but I am clueless.

Comment: Without an app you'll have to create a web app that does this, or use an [existing website](https://veer.tv/blog/top-13-panorama360-degree-photo-viewers/).